# unresolvable broken packages

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dependencies

I have been desperate to resolve this problem as I am not being able to install certain programs.

my computer says that I have broken packages:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-requests : Depends: python3-chardet (>= 2.2.1) but 2.0.1-1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

But when I check in synaptic manager i can't find any broken packages. I can't re-install `python3-requests` for some reason. And for some reason all the other steps to clean up unmet dependencies or broken packages such as `sudo apt-get install -f`, autoremove, upgrade, etc don't seem to work.

Please someone help!

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned having tried most of the cli's to resolve apt-get issues.  You might first try:

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

After that, try going thought your list again with these included:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove && sudo apt-get autoclean
$ sudo apt-get -f install
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
$ sudo apt remove --purge [problem package]
```

The last command is the name of the problem package(s) that were processing to cause the error.  Replace the brackets and command with the name of the problem package.  If it's more than one remove each one.

Those commands (all of them) have always resolved my broken packages issues.  There are occasions where I have to repeat the list of commands more than once to get everything cleared up.