# i can't upgrade or install app

Tags: software-installation

when i try to upgrade or down app using the terminal it display this

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-ext-pack
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

i think the system stacked here to downloaded the file   downloading:
**http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.6/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.6.vbox-extpack**
how i can i change to the original
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Installing the extension package you linked would not be a culprit.  Running that will install the or reinstall the extensions.

Fix your broken packages by running the commands [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/514825/29012).

You might have to loop through them more than once.  Each loop would provide cleanup residue from the previous loop.  You after looping twice you shouldn't get any errors or warning.

Comment: i try the solution it is still the same it show like this,            Hash mismatch Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.6.vbox-extpack
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-ext-pack (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-ext-pack
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1), i try install Bluetooth app  sudo apt-get install bluez

Comment: I thought the list was complete.  I forget to include an important command in the list.  I just added this command to with a description to the list.  `sudo apt remove --purge  virtualbox-ext-pack`.  Please execute the removal command give the results.

Comment: it is working for me after i execute the remove command , thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks for the acknowledgment.  Glad your issue is resolved! You might consider clicking the checkmark to accept the answer.  This way others with a similar issue can benefit by seeing a workable resolution.